# How do you dynamically set the value for the MaterialUI grid size prop in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, material-ui

When using the Grid size props, such as XL, how can you pass a value dynamically to it in TypeScript ?

For example,
*Update for example clarification

```
import Grid, { GridSize } from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
let value: GridSize = 12/4;
xl={value}
```

> Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'GridSize'

If I setup a type such as,

```
type gridSize = boolean | "auto" | 1 | 2 | 12 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | undefined
```

> Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'boolean | "auto" | 1 | 2 | 12
>   | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | undefined'.ts(2769)

Its the same  issue, how do I convert a number to this type?

** Answer Marked Below that helped, In the end I cast it as GridSize and added some unit tests around it for edgecases.

let value = 12/4 as GridSize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already defined [GridSize](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/Grid/Grid.d.ts) type which you can use in code

```js
export type GridSize = 'auto' | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12;
```

**Example**

```js
import Grid, { GridSize } from "@material-ui/core/Grid";

const App = () => {
  let size: GridSize = 1;

  return <Grid xl={size}>
  </Grid>
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

--Edit

I see that `xl` prop also accepts `boolean` and `undefined`

You can also extend `GridSize` type to include these two.

```js
type NewGridSize = GridSize | boolean | undefined;

let size: NewGridSize  = undefined;
```

--Edit

Typescript doesn't have such advanced flow control analysis to assume this is `3`

In such case you have to do dirty trick to cast it to any.

```js
let value: GridSize = 12/4 as any;
```

Or you can make typesguard ( that would be overkill though )

```js
function compute(value: any): value is 3 {
  return value;
}
```

Comment: Its the same issue though, Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'GridSize'.ts(2322)

Comment: What typescript version are you using?

Comment: "typescript": "^3.7.5"

Comment: Im marking your comment as the solution because it got me halfway there. I then found this because of your comments and got me all the way there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51971705/reactjs-typescript-type-number-is-not-assignable-to-type-0-8-16-24-3

Comment: Updated answer a bit. Hope it helps.